# Other than Franco Rasetti, how many scientists refused to work on the Manhattan Project on moral grounds?

Tags: physicists, nuclear-physics, world-war-2

[Franco Rasetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco_Rasetti) was an American-Italian physicist. He was born in Italy and obtained his laurea in physics at the university of Pisa. Fermi invited him to join his research group at the University of Rome. In 1934, he along with Enrico Fermi, discovered key processes leading to nuclear fission - in particular, the artificial radioactivity of flourine and aluminium - which would prove to be important in the development of the atomic bomb.

However, unlike many, he refused to work on the Manhattan project on moral grounds.

How many others were there — do we know?

Comment: Please share what research you have already done. A one minute Google check came up with two possible candidates: [[1](https://www.atomicheritage.org/profile/lise-meitner)] Lise Meitner (1878-1968) was an Austrian physicist. Meitner was part of the team that discovered and explained nuclear fission and foresaw its explosive potential. She refused to work on the Manhattan Project at Los Alamos, declaring,  "I will have nothing to do with a bomb!" Her epitaph on her gravestone, written by her nephew Otto Frisch, reads, "Lise Meitner: a physicist who never lost her humanity."

Comment: [[2](https://www.wnyc.org/story/1964-national-book-awards-ceremony/)] "The second part of the ceremony is reserved for a paper delivered by the distinguished physicist and Nobel laureate I. I. Rabi. [...] Rabi was a man of striking moral and ethical principles. He refused to work on the Manhattan Project and never patented any of his discoveries."

Comment: @njuffa: I thought perhaps someone might have made a study of those who refused to work at the Manhattan project. After all, we hear too much about those that did.

Comment: Joseph Rotblat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Rotblat#Manhattan_Project

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah. Great question. I am happy someone has finally asked the question to hopefully recognize the scientists who refused to work on the bomb.  Thus far we have 4.

Comment: @Sedumjoy: Thanks. I have a personal take on this myself as I was interested in nuclear physics, really as a manifestation of wanting to understand fundamental physics, when I was a student but I found the idea of working in nuclear technology intolerable when it involved killing on such a massive scale. Unfortunately these kind of ethical questions are rarely touched upon in science education, particularly physics - maybe more so on in medicine as that field directly deals with people. I think that is an unfortunate lack in our present education system especially when young people ...

Comment: @sedumjoy: ... here in the UK have to specialise so early. One way of doing tgat is to integrate science history into the science syllabus as that entails a broader look at a field at its place in society than science as a collection of techniques entail.